# How do I find/what is my google maps PlaceID?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I’m having a very difficult time finding my PlaceID for google maps-can someone assist? It’s just a 1-time need, and the java tools don’t tell it, it needs to be done through a developer API, which I’m not familiar with.

Google search: https://www.google.com/maps/place/White+Line+Pest+Management,+9988+Niblick+Dr+ste+3,+Roseville,+CA+95678/@38.790787,-121.312663,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x809b23d58ca8dcdf:0xe2dbfbeb3053e5a0

Physical address:
White Line Pest Management
9988 Niblick dr #3
Roseville, Ca 95678

Comment: Not sure what the downvote reasoning is, I am asking a legitimate question.

Comment: I tried using the tool located at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder but it does not seem to recognize the business location.

Comment: https://support.google.com/business/answer/7035772?hl=en&ref_topic=6109351?from=cuf_business_inappropriate_reviews&authuser=1 I’ve tried this but my listing won’t show on the PlaceID. Can someone please help me out? Appreciated.

Comment: Did you create this business recently? Typically it takes up to 7 days to show up in place autocomplete.

Comment: I did, unfortunately it has been a couple of months now. The places text search did work though - thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the query "White Line Roseville" to [Places Text Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests):

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=White%20Line%20Roseville&key=YOUR_KEY`

> "name" : "White Line Pest Management" 
>   "formatted_address" : "9988 Niblick Dr ste 3, Roseville, CA 95678" 
>   "place_id" : "**ChIJ39yojNUjm4ARoOVTMOv72-I**"